# fragment recreation: the map is no more responsive

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-maps-v2

I added a google Map programmatically to a fragment (let's say fragment F1).

The fragment has this in its `onCreate()`:

```
    mMapFragment = SupportMapFragment.newInstance();
```

this in its `onCreateView`:

```
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction= getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.act_complete_track_f1_frameLayout, mMapFragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

and this in its `onStart()`

```
this.mMap= mMapFragment.getMap();
        if(mMap == null){
            //controllo se sul dispositivo si e' riusciti ad ottenere un google maps service (es: assenza di permessi, componenti di google play services mancanti).
            //Nel caso non fossimo riusciti, elimino la mappa per un graceful degradation
            getView().findViewById(R.id.act_complete_track_f1_frameLayout).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
```

Now: if I interact with the map, everything works. But if the main fragment is recreated (for example by rotating the phone), the map is redrawn BUT it's not responsive anymore: I can click the zoom buttons, but nothing happens for example.

Why is that? How can I handle this?

Comment: You should look at this--
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14804137/recycle-android-maps-v2-supportmapfragment-when-rotating

Comment: thanks! i'll have a look by the end of the day