# How to handle when screen was rotated with map?

Tags: android, google-maps, screen-rotation

first of all I wanted to don't make full reloading of map after screen rotation and i read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20589936/android-dont-refresh-google-maps-v2-on-rotation) and add `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"` to my Manifest file, but i want to change zoom after screen rotation, how can i make it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add also this method to your activity:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {

    } else {

    }
}
```

And handle there what you want :D

Comment: But what can I do if I use map in fragment?

Comment: Change the zoom of the map in this method